# Using HTML5 download attribute with files storage on Firebase Cloud Storage from a page hosted on Firebase Hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm hosting a JavaScript SPA on Firebase Hosting and have files (XML in my case) publicly available on a Firebase Cloud Storage bucket. AFAICT, the `download` attribute on an anchor tag won't work on a file hosted in FCS because the `download` attribute requires the same-origin policy and FCS doesn't support custom domains.

Is there a way to make files hosted by FCS downloadable via an anchor tag with the `download` attribute from a page served from Firebase Hosting?